# MessagingException initializing JMS with spring

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I just wanted to read messages from a queue using spring and got a lot of

```
no dispatcher for MessageDispatch
```

DEBUG logs. I want to use the method `JmsMessagingTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` to automatically convert a received message to the target class. In the example I removed it by `JmsMessagingTemplate.receive()`.

Now I stripped down the code for this question.
Code is:

```
public class JmsReceiver {

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMsgTemplate;

    private Queue queue;

    public JmsReceiver() {
    }

    public JmsReceiver(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void nowReceive() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                Object o = jmsMsgTemplate.receive(this.queue);
                System.out.println(o);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Spring config is:

```
<bean id="targetConnectionFactory"
    class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory"
        ref="activeMqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="activeMqConnectionFactory"
    class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="targetConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="messagesQueueJndi"
    jndi-name="jms/queue/LogMessagesT" />

<bean id="messageReceiver "
    class="com.objectbyte.measuretemp.server.main.JmsReceiver"
    init-method="nowReceive">
    <constructor-arg ref="messagesQueueJndi" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsMsgTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Logs are:

```
...
12:59:28.586 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer - on close, rollback duplicate: ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:39:1:1
...

13:16:01.018 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@48688] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection - org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection$3@77d4a1c3 no dispatcher for MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, message = ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 460, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:92:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:92:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1545993359316, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1545993359316, brokerOutTime = 1545999359167, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@1760a940, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@4b531f68, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {_type=[B, __AMQ_CID=ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-0:1, timestamp=1545993359314}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }, redeliveryCounter = 0} in {ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:-1:1=org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer@5201f451}
13:16:01.084 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@48688] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection - org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection$3@6800e43b no dispatcher for MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, message = ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 465, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:93:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:93:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1545993360818, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1545993360819, brokerOutTime = 1545999359167, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@3a089a41, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@28301ee9, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {_type=[B, __AMQ_CID=ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-0:1, timestamp=1545993360815}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }, redeliveryCounter = 0} in {ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:-1:1=org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer@5201f451}
13:16:01.270 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@48688] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection - org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection$3@3a6d82db no dispatcher for MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:1:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, message = ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 480, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:96:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-1:1:96:1, destination = queue://LogMessages, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1545993362964, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1545993362965, brokerOutTime = 1545999359167, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@95043d0, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@56c521f0, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {_type=[B, __AMQ_CID=ID:Lando-37577-1545993352355-0:1, timestamp=1545993362955}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null }, redeliveryCounter = 0} in {ID:Lando-40433-1545999355422-1:1:-1:1=org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer@5201f451}
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Connection closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Connection closed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: Connection closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Connection closed
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.convertJmsException(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:454)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.doReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:379)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.doReceive(JmsMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageReceivingTemplate.receive(AbstractMessageReceivingTemplate.java:46)
```

So my questions are: Why there is no dispatcher and why there are the exceptions?

Comment: Just solved it using DefaultMessageListenerContainer instead of JmsMessagingTemplate.receive().